# Pinning typescript version during cdk init

Tags: typescript, npm, aws-cdk

I am creating a new CDK app in typescript using the following command:

```
npx --yes cdk@1.138.2 init app --language typescript --generate-only
```

The `package.json` file thus generated has a `typescript` version `^3.9.7`. I would like to use version `4.6.4` instead. How can I pass the parameter to force `cdk init` to use the desired version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDK (v1 and v2) work with Typescript v4. You can manually edit the Typescript vesion in `package.json` to the desired  version at any time. Run `npm outdated` to preview, `npm update` to update the packages. Npm will yell at you if there are dependency conflicts.

Note:  CDK v1 is in [maintenance mode](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19836).  Initialize a current [v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrating-v2.html) project with `npx --yes cdk init ...`

Comment: yes i can def update package.json but i was wondering if we can do that during "cdk init"

Comment: @Darth.Vader  No, `cdk init` [does not expose options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-ref) to modify the versions of the Typescript app template's dependencies.